# Using Python3.x rename a column name of a dataframe with user provided new column name in console window

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

How to rename a column name of my DataFrame with the 'user provided **new column name** in the **console screen**'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have a dataframe like this

```py
>>> df
   A  B  C
0  1  9  1
1  4  7  2
2  3  7  6
3  6  1  6
4  8  1  9
```

And you want to rename the column `B` to that given by user:

```py
>>> col_name = input("Enter Column Name: ")
Enter Column Name: test
```

---

```py
>>> col_names = df.columns.tolist()
>>> col_names
['A', 'B', 'C']
>>> col_names[1] = col_name
>>> col_names
['A', 'test', 'C']
>>> df.columns = col_names
>>> df
   A  test  C
0  1     9  1
1  4     7  2
2  3     7  6
3  6     1  6
4  8     1  9
```